# Magento images not showing on front end

Tags: image, magento

I'm using Magento 1.4. I have two website set up. If I upload images to Website A, they appear fine on both front and back end. If I upload or import images to Website B, they do not appear on the front end, only the backend. I'm completely stuck. I'm happy to provide any additional details that may be helpful, but am so frustrated I'm not sure what is necessary info to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem., After someone suggested delting the .htaccess file in /media (which is of course a bad idea) ich chekced all the parameters and found that both

Options All -Indexes

and

Options +FollowSymLinks

got me an error 500.
commenting them out fixed the problem. I also replaced

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

with

```
 Options  +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
 Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Helped me through too.

Comment: great. worked for backend and frontend too.Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just Rename your .htaccess file inside the /media directory to .htaccess-old. This will absolutely resolve your image issue. - See more at: http://www.viraljetani.com/programming/magento-images-not-appearing-on-frontend-as-well-as-backend-on-godaddy-server#sthash.Uxd9kXqI.dpuf

Comment: Great. Worked in frontend. thanks a lot.But backend not fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your **/media** folder is writeable.

Answer (score 4):

Try

- deleting the cache
- rebuilding indexes

Then:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

SSH from the root of magento, if you working live

Answer (score 3):

If you use big images, try to increase 'memory_limit' parameter in your 'php.ini' file.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing the correct "Store View" for that product.

Comment: this is a life saver! thanks. wasted hours and hours with this one.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a 1950x1950px product photo that was visible in the admin panel but not on the front of the site. Reducing it to 1600x1600px and re-uploading it caused it to be visible in both locations.

Comment: I had the same but it would show up on the category page but not on the product page (I'd get a placeholder image instead) but every time re-sizing it smaller fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe the original uploaded images are to big! Try to keep them under 300kb.

Comment: I found anything under 1mb worked for me but that might be different on different servers.

Answer (score 1):

go to : /public_html/media/catalog/product

rename all the capital letters to lower case. or the oposite.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure also that your owner/group is correctly set for media files. For my server, this is apache/apache and we set the permissions like so:

`$ chown -R apache:apache media/catalog/`

Hope that helps someone. FYI: You might want to run Elzo's answer first to restore proper permissions then do the above.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've had PNG images not show up on the front end (they show blank not placeholder) even though they show up fine in the back-end.

Re saving them as jpegs or saving them as PNG from a different editor fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction

1. Go to 'Cache Storage Management' and click on 'Flush Magento Cache', 'Flush Cache Storage', 'Flush Catalog Images Cache' & 'Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache'
2. Go to 'Index Management', click on 'Select All' and then select 'Reindex Data' from drop-down and submit.

Do this process 3-4 times, then have look at front-end with CTRL+F5. Now images will show-up.
Make sure htaccess is in working mode.