# change Magento to new server, images of existing product do not shown in frontend

Tags: magento

I have moved a Magento website to a new server to optimize speed. All images appear to be replaced by image placeholders. I tried to set permission for media to 777, when I delete cache media folder and refresh, a new cache folder is created automatically, but only with placeholder images inside. I  flushed image cache, reindex in magento backend but still no hope. What should I do now?

Somethings might be helpful:

. It's fine to create new product with images
. Flush cache, only placeholders images are created
. tried to use magento-cleanup.php, no hope
. tried to remove .htaccess in media folder
. the images of products are there in the media folder, just not in cache folder. Magento only looks at the cache folder for image :(

Comment: After moving to the new server, did you purge var/cache? Is there anything in apache error log (missing read permissions or something)? What is in var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your time. I do not move var folder to new server. instead I created a clean var folder. I check the log and see no error.

Comment: Magento is like a box of chocolates, you never know what you're gonna get. Good to see you've made the switch from the shrimp industry to ecommerce.

Answer (score 1):

i think "gd library" on your server is not install yet, so please contect your server...
because this library for images...
After "gd library" reindex and clear all cache and also give full permission to the media folder and cache located in product folder

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rebuild all indexes as well as flush cache in the administration area. Further, install a new browser, like opera, & revisit your site. I have had similar problems while working on development servers with copies of my current live site. And also during the three moves/redeploys done over the past year.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before and it was because I didn't move over the `/media/catalog/product/cache/`.

make sure that folder is on your server and the media folder has proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction

1. Go to 'Cache Storage Management' and click on 'Flush Magento Cache', 'Flush Cache Storage', 'Flush Catalog Images Cache' & 'Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache'
2. Go to 'Index Management', click on 'Select All' and then select 'Reindex Data' from drop-down and submit.

Do this process 3-4 times, then have look at front-end with CTRL+F5. Now images will show-up.
Make sure htaccess is in working mode.

This  answer also posted at [Magento images not showing on front end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422481/magento-images-not-showing-on-front-end/17427279#17427279).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue in past, When i move my magento site local to new server suddenly images disappear on front end and back end too.
After very debugging i got the below solution.

In my case i went to /public_html/media/catalog/product and renamed all the capital letters to lower case.

If your all directory has lower case then renamed it to capital letters.

After this my all products displays as it is.

I hope it will help you.

Answer From: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/10/product-images-not-display-after-move.html